# What RFID options exist for iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ipod-touch

If I wanted to use an iOS device (iPhone, iPod Touch, or iPad) to gather data from RFID chips on equipment in a motor pool, what would I need? Is it even possible today?

Comment: You might like this video about an RFID reader for iOS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hLJOXAZulA

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I was hoping there was some sort of dongle/app combination (like Square for payments) that would RFID-enable devices. It sure would be nice to have NFC built in to the next generation of iOS devices.

Answer (score 5):

What type of RFID tags are you trying to read?  For a motor pool, I would expect you are looking for UHF Gen 2 RFID or even active tags (like Bluetooth LE) as opposed to NFC where you would need to be standing right at the tag on the auto to read it.

We are developing a UHF Gen 2 RFID system for iOS/Android.  The device, unfortunately, needs to be larger than a square since the 10' read range of UHF Gen 2 RFID requires a bigger antenna. Our [dev site](http://dev.ugrokit.com) explains this.

Comment: What are the cards commonly used in ID tags for checking in and out at work etc.?

Answer (score 2):

check out TSL UK - their 1128 docks iPads etc. http://www.tsl.uk.com/products/1128-bluetooth-handheld-uhf-rfid-reader/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at www.touchtechnologies.co.uk for details on our r-touch solution that turns iOS devices into RFID (GenII) &/or barcode reading devices. Really neat, one charger charges both dock &iOS device simultaneously!!

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to http://AsReader.com for UHF and UF RFID solutions for iOS devices.  They have compact dock style readers that can move between iPod touch, iPhone, and iPad mini, Air, & Pro.  Their readers range from 250 mW to 1 Watt in power and have a unique magnetic charging system. Thousands of these readers are in use at a major automobile manufacturer in Japan as well, so your use for motor pool might be a great fit.

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a RFID dongle that is compatible for iOS devices. 
Power is about 1/4 watt.

Comment: Please show what kind you mean. I could also say there's Aliens around, but where's the fact?